# laravel OrderBy and sum

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, eloquent, aggregate-functions

This question seems so silly but it's annoying me.

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 | account_id | order_id | sales | profit | currency | date     |
 |---------------------------------------------------|-----------
 |    10      |   100    | 550   |  10    | USD      |2016-10-11|
 |    10      |   101    | 144   |  4     | NZD      |2016-10-12|
 |    9       |   102    | 429   |  44    | NZD      |2016-10-13|
 |    10      |   103    | 797   |  80    | NZD      |2016-10-14|
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to sum of profit by currency

```
$account = App\Account::find(10);

$collection = $account
                ->orders()                # relation between order and account
                ->completedLastMonth()    # scope of dates,
                ->groupBy('currency')     # group by currency
                ->sum('profit')           # sum of profit
```

but the `$collection` is 94.

So I want result something like this

```
$collection = [
    'USD' => 10,       # total profit of USD 10 for account 10
    'NZD' => 84        # total profit of NZD 80 + 4 = 84 for account 10
]
```

**I have logic of relation between account and Orders and Last Month Scope, Please help me for Aggregate SUM and GROUP BY**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$account = App\Account::find(10);
$collection = $account
                ->orders()                # relation between order and account
                ->completedLastMonth()    # scope of dates,
                ->groupBy('currency')     # group by currency
                ->selectRaw('sum(profit) as sum, currency')
                ->lists('sum','currency');
```

Comment: reasons for download will be appreciated.

Comment: My question is not about `completedLastMonth()` or `orders ()`. [https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Builder.php#LC55](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Builder.php#LC55) return from query. it's not query. I need `collection` in return not `string`